# How to make a list by dates being in a row in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R so I apologize if this is a basic question. I have a df with 12k days of river height data. I've made a filter for when the river is > 28ft. But now i would like to break this filtered df into a list for when the river is >28 ft for x consecutive days.. So for instance if the river is >28ft for 20 days i would like that to be grouped together.

```
library(dplyr)

RawData <- read.csv("c:/Users/Anthony/Desktop/R/CSVRiverData.csv")

RiverData <- cbind(data.frame(as.Date(RawData$Row.Labels, format = "%m/%d/%Y")), 
                   RawData$Average.of.height)

colnames(RiverData) <- c("Date","RiverHeight")


Filt_River_Data <- filter(RiverData,RiverData$RiverHeight >28)

Date_Diff <- data.frame(Filt_River_Data$Date - lag(Filt_River_Data$Date, 1L))
```

Comment: See `?rle`. Sometimes it's useful to steal `data.table::rleid`, e.g. `RiverData %>% group_by(days_above_28 = data.table::rleid(RiverHeight > 28)) %>% filter(RiverHeight > 28, n() > 20)` Also note that you shouldn't use `$` subsetting in dplyr verbs; just refer to the variable directly, and it knows to look in the data frame you've passed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my brute force approach to get the number of consecutive days and then group them. There may be a more elegant solution out there somewhere but here is a simple way to do it with loops.

```
# get some reasonable pseudo data
library(forecast)
rd <- rnorm(1010,mean=28,sd=10)
rd <- forecast::ma(rd,order=10)
rd <- rd[!(is.na(rd))]
temp.dd <- seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"),by=1,length.out=length(rd))
RiverData <- data.frame(temp.dd,rd)
colnames(RiverData) <- c('Date','RiverHeight')

# add vector to df and calculate number of consecutive days
## assume that you want to calcualte # consecutive days based on raw data, not pre-filtered
RiverData$numConDays <- rep(NA,nrow(RiverData))
count = 0
h_thresh <- 28
for (i in 1:nrow(RiverData)) {
  if (RiverData$RiverHeight[i] >= h_thresh) {
    count = count + 1
  } else {
    count = 0
  }
  RiverData$numConDays[i] <- count
}

# now you can filter as you wish
## the first condition of > h_thresh shouldn't be necessary
RiverDataSubset <- RiverData[(RiverData$RiverHeight > h_thresh & RiverData$numConDays > 20),]
head(RiverDataSubset)

# get the grouping for each set
## assumes daily data
RiverDataSubset$group <- rep(NA,nrow(RiverDataSubset))
gg <- 1
RiverDataSubset$group[1] <- gg
for (i in 2:nrow(RiverDataSubset)) {
  if (as.numeric(difftime(RiverDataSubset$Date[i],RiverDataSubset$Date[i-1])) != 1) {
    gg <- gg +1
  }
  RiverDataSubset$group[i] <- gg
}
```

Comment: This works great!! appreciate it very much. Thank you.